# A process have less than 512 virtual memory and 50,000 handles, but report "Not enough virtual memory". Why?

Tags: windows, memory, out-of-memory, native, handle

I'm wondering what can contribute to that a process report "Not enough virtual memory or paging file quota is available to complete the specified operation." while the virtual memory is less than 600m, handles count is less than 50,000, and physical memory is enough?
     Some days ago, I met such an issue:
   One Java program, which utilize serial port by COMM, run into native OOM: "can't create native thread". Which implementation based on win32com.dll and comm.jar.
     I have used processexplorer to monitor the java process, the virtual size of the process is less than 512M, there seems to be some Event handles leak, but when the process crash, the handles was counted as 50000. As I know, one 32bit process can have up to 16m handles.
     I used windbg to debug the program, after setting one breakpoint at os::create_thread and check the lasterror and NTStatusCode, the last status code is C0000017. 
     The thread count is never large than 10. This is not related to thread, at least not obviously.

Comment: Having 50,000 handles is a giant leak somewhere in the program.  The default process quota for handles is 10,000; sounds like that was already extended.  The next one that falls over is the kernel memory pool.  You'd better focus on plugging that leak.

Comment: 10,000 seems to be not accurate, in a test program, I　can create more than 1611574 handles. I have seen a post which said 10,000 is the quota, but test show the threshold is far higher than 10,000

Comment: Isn't the 10,000 quota for GUI handles not kernel handles?

Comment: Got it, seems that the 10,000 is about GDI, but where can find an official statement?

Comment: Error 0x17 is "Data error (cyclic redundancy check)."  Could be a faulty disk, perhaps?  Where are you seeing the "not enough virtual memory" error?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx